# C++ Problem with OMP (#pragma omp critical)

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

1. I have below task to do:
   Transform double integrate() function, which calculates integrate using trapezium method. Your function should be named integrate_omp and use multithreading to speed up calculations.

```
double integrate(double x_min, double x_max, double step, std::function<double(double)> func) {
    double retval = 0;
    double half_step = step / 2.0;
    for (double x = x_min; x + step <= x_max; x += step) {
        double x1 = x;
        double x2 = std::min(x + step, x_max);
       // std::cout << "Mnoze " << x1 << " z " << x2 << " oraz licze " << licznik++ << std::endl;
        retval += (func(x1) + func(x2)) * half_step;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

2. I tried to do it on my own and i did(code below), but i get different outcome every time. i know that i should use

```
#pragma omp critical
```

, but i dont know where to put it.

```
 double integrate_omp(double x_min, double x_max, double step, std::function<double(double)> func) {
 double retval = 0;
 double half_step = step / 2.0;
 int numOfIt = std::ceil((x_max - x_min) / step);
 int i;
 double x1, x2;
 double sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) 
 for (i = 0; i < numOfIt; i++)
 {
         x1 = x_min + i * step;
         x2 = std::min(x_min + step + i * step, x_max);
         retval+= (func(x1) + func(x2)) * half_step;

 }

 return retval;
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQ1k_YpyG_A&list=PLLX-Q6B8xqZ8n8bwjGdzBJ25X2utwnoEG&index=6 I think this and the next video may help you. (starting from 7:52)

Comment: You do not need a critical section. You need a reduction. It looks like a homework, so discover about reduction in omp.

Comment: There were nothing about reduction in omp on out lesson. Our teacher said only about #pragma omp critical and #pragma omp barrier, and homework was in this section of our lecture. Anyway i decided to find out about reduction in omp, and it didnt work for me. I changed 1 line:
```
#pragma omp paraller for private(i) \
reduction(+:retval)

Comment: There is another thing that is wrong due to the same reason why you need `reduction` (well, or a critical section, but the critical section mostly brakes parallelization in you case, so it should be avoided). 
Why did you make `i` private? What does it mean?

Comment: I made it private, because every thread has  its own copy of varaible i, which it iterates.

Comment: OpenMP  `parallel for` works differently, it does not allow threads iterate independently. It parses for-statement and extracts an iteration variable. It gives each thread it’s own value of the iterator for which the thread computes the inner part of the loop, so you never need to bother about ownership of the iterator. But OpenMP cannot do this automatically for other variables. One of the variables you need to care about is `retval`, you fixed it with reduction. But are that all variables you need to be careful about in the parallel section?

Comment: Go back to your first lessons in OpenMP and review what you were taught about the accessibility (`shared` or `private`) of variables in parallel regions.  In this code `x1` and `x2`, having been declared prior to the opening of the parallel region, are automatically `shared` and updates to them are uncoordinated, with non-deterministic results.

Comment: i ve just did it, everyone thanks for help